# appengine magic, almost satisfied but getting null pointer on repl

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop, appengine-magic

I got webapp (made with appengine-magic and lein) working on dev_appserver.sh but because I need more interactivity and less restarting the server I prefer to use repl. Now problem is, that after I do `(require '[appengine-magic.core :as ae])`, `(use 'myapp.core)` and try to serve application `(ae/serve myapp)` I get this exception:

```
[Thrown class java.lang.NullPointerException]

Backtrace:
  0: java.io.File.<init>(File.java:360)
  1: sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  2: sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
  3: sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
  4: java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
  5: clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeConstructor(Reflector.java:160)
  6: appengine_magic.core$start.doInvoke(core_local.clj:85)
  7: clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:439)
  8: appengine_magic.core$serve.doInvoke(core_local.clj:139)
  9: clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:410)
 10: user$eval2264.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
 11: clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5424)
 12: clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5391)
 13: clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2382)
 14: swank.commands.basic$eval_region.invoke(basic.clj:47)
 15: swank.commands.basic$eval_region.invoke(basic.clj:37)
 16: swank.commands.basic$eval807$listener_eval__808.invoke(basic.clj:71)
 17: clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:365)
 18: user$eval2262.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE)
 19: clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5424)
 20: clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5391)
 21: clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2382)
 22: swank.core$eval_in_emacs_package.invoke(core.clj:92)
 23: swank.core$eval_for_emacs.invoke(core.clj:239)
 24: clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:373)
 25: clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:167)
 26: clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:482)
 27: clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:540)
 28: swank.core$eval_from_control.invoke(core.clj:99)
 29: swank.core$eval_loop.invoke(core.clj:104)
 30: swank.core$spawn_repl_thread$fn__493$fn__494.invoke(core.clj:309)
 31: clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:159)
 32: clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151)
 33: clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:540)
 34: swank.core$spawn_repl_thread$fn__493.doInvoke(core.clj:306)
 35: clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:397)
 36: clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
 37: java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

I have also tried (in-ns 'myapp.core) but same effect. When I paste web app handler straight on repl and serve then it works, but not from my file.

calling myapp or myapp-handler clearly gives the "object" so I should really be on right namespace...

project.clj

```
(defproject myapp "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :dependencies [
        [org.clojure/clojure "1.2.1"]
        [compojure "0.6.2"]
        ]
  :dev-dependencies [
            [appengine-magic "0.4.1"]
            [ring/ring-devel "0.3.7"]
            ])
```

core.clj is as just simple:

```
(ns myapp.core
    (:use compojure.core)
    (:require [appengine-magic.core :as ae]))

(defroutes myapp-handler
    (GET "/" req
       {:status 200
        :headers {"Content-Type" "text/plain"}
        :body "Hello, world!!!"}))

(ae/def-appengine-app myapp #'myapp-handler)
```

Comment: perhaps with more of the stacktrace (the part involving your code) I could help more. It would be easier for me to reproduce this if i had the project.clj (assuming leiningen) for the project.

Comment: This is all stacktrace I can get from emacs and project file is really simple. I have ring devel there for wrap reload, but im not using it in this case.

Comment: I have to say I'm getting the same error, was there any idea about how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of repl are you using? I have replicated your project but added

[swank-clojure "1.3.0-SNAPSHOT"]

to the :dev-dependencies. Start a slime repl using the lein swank command and then use slime-connect to connect to it from from emacs. Then I used the same commands as you i.e. (require '[appengine-magic.core :as ae]), (use 'myapp.core) and (ae/serve myapp) it works fine.

Cheers,
  Colin

Comment: I used both lein repl and lein swank but with swank that came with appengine-magic libraries. And weird it gets, today when I deleted all code from file and pasted it back exactly as it was on my example, there was no errors anymore!

I have seen this strange behaviour on PHP couple of times, there is no visible errors on core, but parsing or execution just doesnt work. Maybe its unvisible characters, i dont know... but now its working, exactly same code I have presented on my question...

Comment: Very strange, but at least it's working now. Hopefully it will stay that way!

Answer (score 0):

try running "lein clean" in the project folder before calling (ae/serve myapp).

I had a similar problem where I was AOT compiling the code which was causing problems. I discussed this with the creator of appengine-magic and he suggested removing the AOT compiled classes by running lein clean which solved it.

Answer (score 0):

This symptom (NPE in `java.io.File.<init>`) can also be caused by mistakenly passing e.g. the handler var to `ae/serve` rather than the var created by the `def-appengine-app` macro.